# Is it possible to run 2 different motherboards in parallel?

Tags: windows-8, cpu, motherboard, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to run a motherboard with a 64-bit CPU and another motherboard with a 32-bit CPU etc. etc. in parallel to form a kind of "Super PC" for my hard core games.

**Question 1**

Is it possible in Windows 8.1?

**Question 2**

If it is possible, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Question does not make sense.  All 64-bit processors are 32-bit processors.  What benefit do you gain, or what benefit do you think you gain, from doing what you describe?  There are motherboards with multiple CPU sockets, but most people, would run 2 of the same processor when they do that.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to combine the two motherboards for better ram space and better CPU speed.

Comment: What you are kind of talking about is Beowulf clustering (or parallel computing) and although possible it is not really something that is feasible for a home setup. Also it is not really used for gaming it is more used for data crunching. So long answer is yes in theory, short answer in your case most likely no.

Comment: They not even have the same architecture

Comment: @DilanV - Sounds like you just want a [dual-socketed motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100007629%20600288062).  Each socket would allow you to have 4-8 memory modules for each processor.  You can acomplish, your goal of better performance, without the use two seperate motherboards.  Having one 64-bit CPU  and one 32-bit CPU doesn't make logical sense.

Comment: @Ramhound what about two 64-bit CPU's?

Comment: Did you research dual-socketed motherboards?  Your research will answer that question.

Comment: @Ramhound ok thanks I think I'll rather just buy a gaming pc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Is it possible?" Well, yes, in a sense. It's called having two separate computers. Or, to a lesser degree, virtualization.

The motherboard is what ties all the pieces of a computer together. It hosts system buses, peripheral-hardware interfaces, and so on.

Simplifying a little, **today's hardware isn't designed in such a way that it can be shared between multiple, independent systems running on the hardware simultaneously.** There existed hardware add-ons for early personal computers, like the [Z-80 SoftCard for Apple II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-80_SoftCard) or the [Sidecar for the Amiga 1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulation_on_the_Amiga#MS-DOS_on_Amiga_via_Sidecar_or_Bridgeboard), but these add-ons *were basically whole computers of their own* which tied into the graphics and storage of the host system. On the Apple II this was easy as it was a single-tasking design, and on the Amiga it took specific programming (not entirely unlike whole-system virtualization today).

So while *technically* the answer is "yes, with caveats", *in practice* the answer is "no". You will need to duplicate so many components that you effectively end up with two separate computers, possibly sharing a case (if you have one custom made for your setup). That makes it rather pointless for most people, and thus no market exists so (at least insofar as I know) nobody has spent the time and money to try to do it.

Comment: Okay thanks @Michael Kjorling what about only combining the CPU's?

Comment: @DilanV The CPUs will, at the very least, need some way of cooperating about the installed RAM. That's not something modern contemporary CPUs are designed to do. Again, it *might be possible*, but it's certainly not something you can just do. OSes will likely need to be aware of it too. The alternative is plain old virtualization.